# What is the probability that if $8$ people are split into two groups of $4$ that you are placed with same people twice?

Tags: probability

Binomial coefficient: $8$ people are split into two equal groups. What is the probability that you as a student get in a group with the same $3$ students twice in a row?(total 4 students with yourself)
And how do you do this with 3 people instead of 4?

Really need help with how to think, I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: You should not change the statement of a question after it has been answered.  If you wish to know the probability that you are placed in the same group of people twice when six people are split into two groups of three, the same methods apply.   Two of those people must be in your group the first time.  The second time, there are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ ways to place two of the other five people in your group.  Only one such selection will place the same group of people as before in your group, so the desired probability is $\frac{1}{10}$, as you can check by listing the possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

The way to think about this is to imagine the instructor pulling out 4 people for group $A$ and then the remaining four people become group $B$.

So, when making the groups the second time, you'll end up with the same three people if the instructor selects the four of you, OR if the instructor selects the four people that weren't in your group the first time.

So that's two possibilities out of (number of ways to choose 4 students from 8 total).

The number of ways to choose four students from 8 total is $\binom{8}{4}$, or $\frac{8!}{4!4!}$, or $70$.

So the chance that you end up in the same group as before is $\frac{2}{70}$, or $\frac{1}{35}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks; I was careless typing it into my calculator.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped.

Comment: @Pineapple Just be sure you got the edited version, with $\binom{8}{4} = 70$

Comment: I tried doing it with 3 people instead of 4, but it Doesnt seem to work out the same way?

Answer (score 1):

Three of the other seven students must be in the same group as you the first time.  What we need to calculate is the probability that the same three students are in the same group as you the second time.

The second time your instructor places you in groups, your instructor can choose the other members of your group in $\binom{7}{3}$ ways.  Of these ways, only one will put the same three people in your group as were in your group the first time.  Hence, the probability that the same group of three people will be in your group both times is 
$$\frac{\dbinom{3}{3}}{\dbinom{7}{3}} = \frac{1}{35}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are ${8\choose 4}=70$ ways to choose a group of $4$ from $8$ people, hence $35$ ways to split $8$ people into two groups of $4$. The probability that the second time the split is the same as the first time therefore is ${1\over35}$.

Comment: Do you do the same if its 3 people instead of 4? I tried doing it similar but vant get the correct answer for 3 people, Thanks!

Comment: It's unclear what you mean with "$3$ people". If it's $3$ from $8$ it's not even sure that the student is selected the second time around.